Symfony 7 : Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "Title"
It's mainly a question of understanding, because I've found a solution, but I'm not really convinced.
I've two methods, new and edit as shown below :

    #[Route('film/new', name: 'app_film_new', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(FilmType::class,null,  ['method' => 'POST']);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $film = new film();
            $film = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($film);
            $em->flush();
            
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Le film a bien été créé');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_show_film', ['id' => $film->getId()]);
        } 

        return $this->render('film/new.html.twig', ['form' => $form]);
    }


    #[Route('film/{id}/edit', name: 'app_film_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function update(Film $film, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(FilmType::class, $film, ['method' => 'POST']);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $film = $form->getData();
            
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Le film a bien été modifié');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_show_film', ['id' => $film->getId()]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('film/edit.html.twig', ['film' => $film, 'form' => $form]);
    }


In my FilmEntity, I have this about Title property, for example :

    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:"Le titre ne peut pas être vide.")]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable:false)]
    private ?string $titre = null;

When I do a test with the new form, and if I put anything in the Title field (and delete the "required" attribute of this field"), any problem : I can see form with an error below the Title field, as the constraint ask it.
But when I do the same thing with the edit form, in that case, I've the error :

Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "titre".

I've resolved it by adding a "?" before "string" in the setter.
    public function setTitre(?string $titre): static
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

But I don't understand why there is this behavior only in one case, and why Constraint aren't read before setters.
Is there someone to explain it to me ?
Thanks.

The behavior you're encountering where the constraint isn't respected during form submission in the edit case but works fine in the new case is likely due to how Symfony handles form data binding.
In the new case, when you create a new Film object, Symfony's form system initializes all properties of the object to their default values, which in PHP often means null for nullable properties like $titre. When you submit the form, Symfony binds the form data to the object, and since the form field is not empty, it sets the titre property to the submitted value. If the value doesn't satisfy the constraint, Symfony shows the error correctly.
However, in the edit case, Symfony retrieves an existing Film object from the database. If the titre property of that object is null in the database, and your form field is not marked as required, Symfony doesn't see any data for the titre field in the submitted form, and hence it doesn't set the titre property to anything. Consequently, when Symfony tries to validate the object, it encounters a null value for titre, which violates the constraint expecting a string.
By making the titre property nullable in the entity and adjusting the setter accordingly, you're effectively telling Symfony that it's acceptable for the titre property to be null, which resolves the validation error.
Regarding why constraints aren't read before setters, Symfony's form system first sets the data onto the object and then validates it. This sequence ensures that any transformations or manipulations applied by setters are taken into account during validation. While this behavior might seem counterintuitive in some cases, it's generally consistent with how Symfony processes form data.

Thanks @ogash for your clear answer.
However, there is still some misunderstandings : When I do an edition on an existant film, with a title not null in database, if I try to update this film by submitting the form with an empty field, I don't see the constraint error, but still the symfony error.
in other words :
I've a film in database : {id: 1, title: "Pocahontas"}
I attempt to hack the edit form by submitting without title (emty field)
I've the bug error, and not the pretty constraint error in form.
So if people want to hack forms, that breaks app instead of display error ?

The other way to resolve this bug is to put in formType builder this option :
->add('titre', TextType::class, [ 'empty_data' => '' ])
But the problem is the same for me : there is no way to do that with automation, for all fields we want not null ? Because without this, a form hack can break our forms.
